# How do world bosses work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm looking for info on world bosses, specifically:

- What are the respawn times?
- Is there 1 per planet?
- Where are they located?
- Are there any special quests to summon a world boss?

Comment: Are you trying to ask us 4 separate questions in 1 question here? Or are you're looking for one source elsewhere on the 'net that answers all these questions?

Comment: one source would be ideal but all this information is related to the one topic of 'What are the mechanics of world bosses?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time I feel that this question cannot be answered completely. Zam(Torhead) is working on building their database which will most likely have what you are looking for eventually. For the time being I will direct you to a thread on the SWTOR community forums. This thread is being updated fairly regularly, has names, levels, locations, coordinates, maps, and pictures of most of the world bosses that players have found and posted on the thread.

The thread has also been stickied by a Community Rep so it is hopefully going to become/stay a solid list.

You can view this thread here -> [Heroic World Boss List](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=105905)